# How to pass radio input type value from PHP while loop to HTML?

Tags: php, html

I have radio button in a PHP while-loop.

I am storing the first row value in the value of radio button.

I need to pass the value of radio button in HTML `a href`.

How to pass that value with both PHP and HTML in same page??

My code:

index.php

```
<html>
<body>
  <a href="#" style="margin-left:21px "><img src="images/print_label.png" name="Image3" width="152" height="110" border="0" align="top" style="margin-top:10px"></a>
<?php

    include "db.php";
    require_once "purna_insert_orders_to_ship.php";
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
    if($_POST['value'] == 'readytoship') {
        // query to get all Fitzgerald records
        $query = "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE status='readytoship'";
    }
    elseif($_POST['value'] == 'readytodispatch') {
        // query to get all Herring records
        $query = "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE status='readytodispatch'";
    } else {
        // query to get all records
        $query = "SELECT * FROM orders";
    }
    $sql = mysql_query($query);

    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($sql);
    if($num_rows >= 1)
        {

        echo "<div id='showmenu' class='scroll'>";  

        echo "<table id='table_struct' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1' border='1' width='400' height='30'>
         <tr class='tr_class' bgcolor='white'>
         <td align='center' style='font-weight:bold'> Select </td>
         <td align='center' style='font-weight:bold'> Po Id </td>
         <td align='center' style='font-weight:bold'> Customer Name </td>

         <td align='center' style='font-weight:bold'> quantity </td>

         <td align='center' style='font-weight:bold'> price </td>
         <td align='center' style='font-weight:bold'> status </td>

        </tr>";
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
        {
                echo "<tr height='20' data-order_id='".$row['po_id']."'>
                <td align='center'><input type='radio' class='case' name='radio' value='".$row['po_id']."'></td>
                <td align='center'>".$row['po_id']."</td>
                <td align='center'>".$row['customer_name']."</td>

                <td align='center'>".$row['quantity']."</td>

                <td align='center'>".$row['price']."</td>
                <td align='center'>".$row['status']."</td>
                ";

                echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
        echo "</div>";
    }
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone please help me out??

Comment: You mean `<input type="radio" name="name" value="yourvalue"/>` ?

Comment: ya like dat only am doing.. after that how to call that value in html ahref.

Comment: I have posted answer considering you want to do in ajax call, if not pls specify your need in my answer. so that i can update and help you

Answer (score 0):

To use the value in an anchor tag, you would need to invoke the GET method as follows:

```
<a href="mypage.php?po_id={row['po_id']}">Click here</a>
```

But, since it is in a radio button, you might want to consider using an HTML form with submit button rather than an anchor tag.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call that value in html ahref then you should need some jquery too

First you should echo some value in your radio button

```
<input type="radio"  name="buttonval" id="smallBtn" value="yourvalue"/>
```

Then in the change even of the radio button, You shall fire the event

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("input[name=buttonval]").on('change', function(){
    var $postID = $('input:radio[name=buttonval]:checked').val();
    $postID = "="+$postID;
    });
    $.ajax ({
       type: "GET",
       url: "localhost/ajax/buttonvaluereceiver.php",
       data: {"postID" : $postID }
    });
});
</script>
```

and in the success event of the ajax call you will get the result of what `buttonvaluereceiver.php` file does

Update :

As you need to do instantly in radio button change I am updating my answer for you

**Here is the html and script**

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name='frm' id='frm'>
<input type='radio' id='test' value='rad' name='rad'>
</form>

Your link : 

<div id='link'></div>
<script>
$("input").change(function(){
    var data = $("#frm").serialize();


        Call();        

});

function Call()
    {
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url : "result.php",
        data : $("#frm").serialize(),
        success : function(data)
        {
        console.log(data);

        $("#link").html(data);
        }
    },"json");
 }

</script>
```

**Here is the php that creates your link**

```
<?php 

echo "<a href='url.php?id".$_POST['rad']."'>Click here</a>";
?>
```

You can change the url and values according to your need.

Comment: Yes , Call it and convey what it does

Comment: can u provide js filddle demo for this?? pls

Comment: Ok i can, give but may i know what is the ouput need if you select the radio button and not select the radio button ?

Comment: actually am passing the the order number in the value of radio button. Order number is dynamic. so if i select the radio button i have to pass that value(order number) to a href which is in html..  If i click that href link the corresponding info abt dat order number wil get display

Comment: Here is the fiddle that show passing the value via radio button http://jsfiddle.net/Uwcuz/2671/

Comment: Have a look on the fiddle i provided above, For the thing that you needed. you can do this easily via jquery and ajax call. If you want me to help that convey it too :)

Comment: ya dat is k but am not using submit button.. without submit button how to do

Comment: In the radio button on change event

Comment: can u provide any xample for that

Comment: Yes was accessing via mobile. Will provide shortly

Comment: k waiting can you provide within an hour pls??

Comment: can u provide here only pls